# Ansible - how to check if all elements on list are the same?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

We have list, like:
`['A', 'A']`
How to check if list contains only elements `A`?  (Yes, it is exactly string).

For example, for
`['A']`, `['A','A','A','A']` True should be returned, however for
`[]`, `['A','A', 'B']` False should be returned.

Is there exists any elegant way to express it?

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
- set_fact:
    sample:
      - A
      - A
- set_fact:
    has_unique_val: "{{ sample | unique | length == 1 }}"
- debug:
    var: has_unique_val
```

- `sample | unique | length` this reduces the list to only unique values, then counts how many values are returned. If there is only one value, 1 will be returned, otherwise 0 or >1
- `== 1` returns true if the count is 1, otherwise false